# Notification sound change

Tags: notifications

This is not something I normally mess with but the notification pop sound really annoys me.  I turned the volume down but do like to have a sound.  Any advice on how this can be changed? I guess it's a sound file somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer, I did for example  `sudo mv bell.oga bell2.oga` and then `sudo cp camera-shutter.oga bell.oga` to check that I could replace the sound and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

Speaker icon in panel > Sound settings > Sound effects > Mute button

#### Option 2

Navigate to folder: `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo` and change `bell.oga` (requires sudo) to another stereo ogg sound effect

#### Option 3

Download the `freedesktop` theme to your home folder http://people.ubuntu.com/~dylanmccall/soundgallery/ and save it in ~/.local/share/sounds/
This doesn't require sudo, and you can then edit this, and

Now you can go to:

Speaker icon in panel > Sound settings > Sound effects

And select a different sound!

Hopefully this fuels your imagination and you are able to make a custom theme you are happy with!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (elementary OS 5.0 - Juno):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga
sudo rm /usr/share/sounds/elementary/stereo/audio-volume-change.wav
```

Then I rebooted my computer but restarting only the desktop manager should do it too.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/9qibas/disable_volume_sound/eh0n9hn/